# How to get max value from the oneToMany table using hibernate query language

Tags: java, hibernate, join, max, hql

The following is my schemma structure

```
sub_roles
id
name
role_id
parent_id

roles
id
name
user_id
last_updated

user
id
name
type
```

I want to fetch the users with recently modified role information based on parent_id

I wrote the following query to fetch the users based on parent_id as follows

```
select sr.role.user, sr.parent, sr.role from SubRole sr where sr.parent.id in (:parentIds)
```

I want to get recently updated user role. How to achieve this by modifying the above query

Comment: sub_roles has foreign key role_id. What parent_id stand for?

Comment: parent_id references a table where sub roles are grouped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select user.id as id, SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(user.name AS CHAR) ORDER BY rl.last_updated desc), ',', 1 ) as name, SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(user.type AS CHAR) ORDER BY rl.last_updated desc), ',', 1 ) as type from sub_roles srl INNER JOIN roles rl on srl.role_id = rl.id INNER JOIN user on rl.user_id = user.id where parent_id in (:parentIds) group by user.id;
```

P.S. : Not Tested

Comment: I want to get the single recently updated role for the user based on parent_id

Comment: add 'limit 1' at the end of the query

Comment: adding limit 1 at the end returns a single result. But my intention is to return the latest roles for each user under a parent. For example user1 => latest role 1, user2 => latest role 2, etc.,

Comment: Edited: check answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
select sr.parent, sr.role, u from SubRole sr JOIN sr.role.user u WHERE sr.parent.id IN (:parentIds)
```